# Percorrer sobre um objeto e suas propriedades

Tags: javascript, objetos

Supondo que eu tenha este *pedaço* de código:

```
let obj = {
  lang: {
    hi: 'Olá, mundo!'
  },

  engine: {
    functions: {
      init: function () {
        return this.lang.hi;
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.engine.functions.init());
```

Como eu faço a função `obj.engine.init()` funcionar, isto é, conseguir chegar até a propriedade `obj.lang.hi`, pela função citada acima.

Comment: altera o `this` pelo o `obj`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O acesso ao objeto através de `obj.engine.functions.init()` está correto. O problema está no código dentro da função `init`:

```
init: function () {
    return this.lang.hi;
}
```

Que usa o `this` como se fosse o `obj` quando na verdade refere ao próprio `functions`. Se trocarmos este acesso por um retorno de um valor fixo vemos que funciona:

```js
let obj = {
  lang: {
    hi: 'Olá, mundo!'
  },

  engine: {
    functions: {
      init: function () {
        return "Dentro de init"; //retornando agora uma string normal
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.engine.functions.init());
```

Na verdade também não consegue aceder ao objeto que contem o `init`, ou seja o objeto pai de dentro do `init` nativamente.

Uma solução seria referenciando o objeto `obj` diretamente com:

```
init: function () {
    return obj.lang.hi;
}
```

Exemplo:

```js
let obj = {
  lang: {
    hi: 'Olá, mundo!'
  },

  engine: {
    functions: {
      init: function () {
        return obj.lang.hi;
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.engine.functions.init());
```

Outra solução seria criando no `functions` uma referência ao `obj` com uma especie de função de inicialização:

```js
let obj = {
  lang: {
    hi: 'Olá, mundo!'
  },
  iniciar: function() { //aqui função para construir a referencia
    this.engine.functions.referenciaObj = this;
  },

  engine: {
    functions: {
      init: function () {
        return this.referenciaObj.lang.hi; //acesso pela referencia interna
      }
    }
  }
};

obj.iniciar(); //iniciar para que a referência exista

console.log(obj.engine.functions.init());
```